# Modularizing peewee

Tags: python, python-module, peewee

Suppose I have a couple of simple models residing in `food.py`:

```
import peewee as pw

db = pw.SqliteDatabase('food.db')

class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Taco(BaseModel):
    has_cheese = pw.BooleanField()

class Spaghetti(BaseModel):
    has_meatballs = pw.BooleanField()

db.connect()

# populate with some data if table doesn't exist
from random import random
if not Taco.table_exists():
    db.create_table(Taco)
    for _ in range(10):
        Taco.create( has_cheese = (random() < 0.5) )
    db.commit()
if not Spaghetti.table_exists():
    db.create_table(Spaghetti)
    for _ in range(10):
        Spaghetti.create( has_meatballs = (random() < 0.5) )
    db.commit()
```

Afterwards, I have `food.py` and `food.db`. But let's say the `Taco` and `Spaghetti` models are becoming large and complicated, so I'd like to split them into different files. Specifically, I'd like to create a `food` folder in my `PYTHONPATH` with the typical hierarchy:

```
food/
    - __init__.py
    - BaseModel.py
    - Taco.py
    - Spaghetti.py
    - db/
        - food.db
```

I'd like to put the models into their respective `.py` files and have an `__init__.py` file that looks something like this:

```
import peewee as pw

db = pw.SqliteDatabase('./db/food.db')

from . import BaseModel
from . import Taco
from . import Spaghetti

db.connect()
```

However, this clearly doesn't work because `BaseModel.py` can't access `db`. If it is possible to modularize multiple peewee models in this manner, what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the trick is to connect to the database in the `BaseModel.py` file. I will give a full outline of the module contents. Assume that the top-level folder is named `food` and lives in the `PYTHONPATH`. Finally assume that `food.db` exists in `food/db/food.db` and has been populated (e.g., as in the bottom of the very first code block in the question).

Here are the module files:

> __init__.py

```
from Taco import Taco
from Spaghetti import Spaghetti
```

> BaseModel.py

```
import peewee as pw
db = pw.SqliteDatabase('/abs/path/to/food/db/food.db')

class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

> Taco.py

```
import peewee as pw
from BaseModel import BaseModel

class Taco(BaseModel):
    has_cheese = pw.BooleanField()
```

> Spaghetti.py

```
import peewee as pw
from BaseModel import BaseModel

class Spaghetti(BaseModel):
    has_meatballs = pw.BooleanField()
```

---

Now, for example, you can write a script (residing outside the module folder, of course), like:

> main.py

```
import food

for t in food.Taco.select():
    print "Taco", t.id, ("has" if t.has_cheese else "doesn't have"), "cheese"
```

produces:

```
Taco 1 has cheese
Taco 2 has cheese
Taco 3 has cheese
Taco 4 doesn't have cheese
Taco 5 doesn't have cheese
Taco 6 has cheese
Taco 7 has cheese
Taco 8 has cheese
Taco 9 doesn't have cheese
Taco 10 doesn't have cheese
```

Comment: I have tried the modularization, it works when i do not have any foreign keys since it complains of circular imports. How would i go about modularization if i had foreign keys

Comment: here's where I get stuck w circular deps: BaseModel needs db | db.create_tables() needs the Models | Models need BaseModel... which needs db

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the path:

```
__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
db = pw.SqliteDatabase(os.path.join(__location__, 'db/food.db'));
```

---

Try also to implement `__init__` of classes and pass the `db` as an argument to it:

```
class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    def __init__(self, db = None)
        self.database = db
```

than in `__init__.py`:

```
from BaseModel import BaseModel
db = pw.SqliteDatabase('./db/food.db')
bm = BaseModel(db)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I do the same with `Taco.py`, it says the `peewee.OperationalError: no such table: taco` when I try to access the mode's attributes. In fact if my `__init__.py` is nothing but: `import peewee as pw; db = pw.SqliteDatabase('./db/food.db'); db.connect()`, I get the error `peewee.OperationalError: unable to open database file`

Comment: try it with `db = pw.SqliteDatabase('food/db/food.db')`

Comment: That doesn't work either. The error goes away if I use an absolute path, but this makes no difference because I get the `no such table` error the moment I attempt to access model attributes. This happens with or without a `db.connect()` statement before or after passing `db` to `Taco(db)`.

Comment: Even if the issue is barely with the path,  there is no point of using classes if you are not using them as classes.  check my update for fixing the path.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I *am* using them as classes. Unless I'm missing something, this just doesn't work (no matter if the path is fixed). Could you explain how your solution ties in with the other class files in the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: let fix first the path issue, tried using `__location__ `?

Comment: Yes. This is fine. It's when I try to work in models after `BaseModel` where issues happen.

Answer (score 0):

See this post for instructions on modularizing a flask app using peewee:

http://charlesleifer.com/blog/structuring-flask-apps-a-how-to-for-those-coming-from-django/

Comment: I came across your post via google, actually! Unfortunately I'm not using flask, so your method doesn't quite work (see my answer above ((or below??)) for my solution). Precisely the thing I'm trying to accomplish is to break the models into separate files. Your method appears to leave all the models in one file, and it wasn't clear how each model file would share the database instance or where the database instance should be instantiated to do this. This is the problem I've solved above. Thanks, though!

Comment: Hiya. Saw this link in multiple SO posts, read it, but it doesn't address putting each model/table class in a separate file, which is what I think people are after. I read through some peewee docs looking for that. It would be good to have an example like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347404/5739514 in the docs for noobs like us. I've been procrastinating this modularization and now I'm at like 8K lines and have been getting shunned for it. thanks for everything =)